# Why does this aircraft gyroscope has two degrees of freedom?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes

[image]
This is a Directional Gyro Indicator, it is a tied gyro, the spin axis is tied to the aircraft horizontal axis.

I read that this gyroscope has two degrees of freedom.

Please explain why is it so? What is meant by degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a gyroscope, it is normally free to swivel about on its x, y, and z axies: three *degrees of freedom* or independent ways in which it is free to move. One of these axies corresponds to its own rotational axis leaving two axies to display the airplane's *attitude* in *pitch* (nose up or down) and *roll* (banked left or right).

In the specific case of a *directional gyro*, which does not have to display pitch or roll information, the only degree of freedom needed is in the *yaw* sense (turning left or right) plus the rotational degree of freedom of the gyro flywheel, hence, *two* degrees of freedom.

Comment: Why is then that Artifical Horizon is also said to have two degrees of freedom?

Comment: because they are not counting the degree of freedom of the gyroscope's spin axis.